# Failed to include GLUT C++

Tags: c++, glut

I'm using the MinGW compiler, my OS is Windows, GLUT is in my Documents folder and the file (Graphics.cpp) is also in my Documents folder, here it is by the way:

```cpp
#include <GL/glut.h>
void drawSquare(double x1, double y1, double sidelength)
{
    double halfside = sidelength / 2;

    glColor3d(0,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex2d(x1 + halfside, y1 + halfside);
    glVertex2d(x1 + halfside, y1 - halfside);
    glVertex2d(x1 - halfside, y1 - halfside);
    glVertex2d(x1 - halfside, y1 + halfside);

    glEnd();
}
```

But I get this error when I try compiling the code:

```
Graphics.cpp:1:21: fatal error: GL/glut.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GL/glut.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

Can anyone help? Any additional info needed?
Thanks.

Comment: Why is GLUT in your Desktop? You need to actually install it. Have you followed the GLUT installation instructions?

Comment: ***GLUT is in my Desktop*** That does not seem like a good place however it is a matter of opinion. I would not put any code on the desktop.

Comment: After you properly install GLUT make sure that the folder containing the GL folder is in one of the folders that you told the compiler to look for include files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the compiler can not find the header. In gcc use the `-I` flag to include the absolute path to the directory GL/glut.h

https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.html

Comment: Oops, mine is g++, do you know how to do it in g++? Well still, thanks for the answer! I would of upvoted if I had enough reputation.

Comment: gcc and g++ use the same way to specify an include path.

Comment: @drescherjm OK I'll try that then, thank you!